# How to display current time inside a div using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, momentjs

I need to display the current time when I click the button each time, I've achieved the DOM of creating new divs when clicked on button, but I'm not getting the time inside span.

**HTML**

```
        <button onClick="createDiv()">Record Time</button>

        <div id="getText" style="display: none;">
           <span id="showTime"></span>
        </div>
```

**Script**

```
function createDiv()
  
  {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var now = moment().format("h:mm:ss A"); 
    $('#showTime').append(now);

  }
```

As the code above, current time should be displayed on each new div.

Comment: You're appending the div to the body. then appending text to `showTime`. use `.text(now)` instead and forget about the div

Comment: You already have the `div` as a variable, no need to then select a different div/span: `let div =...` `div.innerText = now`

Comment: What's the `div id=getText` / `span id=showTime` actually meant for?  You don't need this if you're adding a new div.  Did you want a *single* div showing the time?  Or a new div each time you click (like a list/record of clicks)?  Looks like people are getting confused with your getText/showTime html.  Yet your question asks "I can create divs, but not getting it in the span* - so why create divs?

Comment: Looks like it's simply because your `getText` is `display:none` - `$("#getText").show()`

Comment: can you please write that line of code entirely? I'm really bad at syntax @freedomn-m

Comment: Here's your code working fine (no code changes) but with `id=getText` simply not hidden!  (so you can *see* it's adding the date)  https://jsfiddle.net/m6vzp2j4/

Comment: *that line of code entirely* - it *is* an entire line - Just add it inside your `createDiv()` method: https://jsfiddle.net/m6vzp2j4/1/ or did you mean the `div.innerText=`, again that *is* an entire line: https://jsfiddle.net/m6vzp2j4/2/

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using jquery in your script, if so simply replace the

line: `$('#showTime').append(now);`

with: `$('#showTime').text(now);`

with vanilla JS you can also do this:

```
function createDiv(){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var now = moment().format("h:mm:ss A"); 
    let timeNow = document.createTextNode(now);
    $('#showTime').append(timeNow);
}
```